# undefined-behavior with FireStore

Tags: xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm on Xcode 9.4 on Mac High Sierra v10.13.4. I have integrated FireStore into my app and I have 'Undefined Behavior Sanitizer' enabled.

When I execute the following command

```
- (void)updateData:(NSDictionary<id, id> *)fields
    completion:(nullable void (^)(NSError *_Nullable error))completion
```

I get this error in the console

```
/Users/<folderName>/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/core/src/firebase/firestore/util/ordered_code.cc:172:21: runtime error: load of misaligned address 0x000106af8a41 for type 'const uint32_t' (aka 'const unsigned int'), which requires 4 byte alignment
0x000106af8a41: note: pointer points here
 69 6e 67  00 76 65 72 73 69 6f 6e  00 54 40 22 4e 53 4e 75  6d 62 65 72 22 2c 52 2c  56 5f 76 65 72

SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /Users/<folderName>/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/core/src/firebase/firestore/util/ordered_code.cc:172:21 in 
/Users/<folderName>/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/core/src/firebase/firestore/util/ordered_code.cc:102:3: runtime error: load of misaligned address 0x000106af8a41 for type 'const uint32_t' (aka 'const unsigned int'), which requires 4 byte alignment

0x000106af8a41: note: pointer points here
69 6e 67  00 76 65 72 73 69 6f 6e  00 54 40 22 4e 53 4e 75  6d 62 65 72 22 2c 52 2c  56 5f 76 65 72


SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /Users/<folderName>/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/core/src/firebase/firestore/util/ordered_code.cc:102:3 in
```

This is easily reproducible

When I have both 'Thread Sanitizer' and 'Undefined Behavior' enabled in Xcode, I see this message in the console.

```
================== WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=59902)

Read of size 8 at 0x7b4c00051750 by thread T10:
#0 leveldb::port::AtomicPointer::Acquire_Load() const atomic_pointer.h:135 (leveldb:x86_64+0x73d55)
#1 leveldb::(anonymous namespace)::Limiter::GetAllowed() const env_posix.cc:80 (leveldb:x86_64+0x15ccd6)
#2 leveldb::(anonymous namespace)::Limiter::Acquire() env_posix.cc:55 (leveldb:x86_64+0x15c768)
#3 leveldb::(anonymous namespace)::PosixEnv::NewRandomAccessFile(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, leveldb::RandomAccessFile**) env_posix.cc:354 (leveldb:x86_64+0x1461d6)
#4 leveldb::TableCache::FindTable(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, leveldb::Cache::Handle**) table_cache.cc:56 (leveldb:x86_64+0x228a50)
#5 leveldb::TableCache::Get(leveldb::ReadOptions const&, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, leveldb::Slice const&, void*, void (*)(void*, leveldb::Slice const&, leveldb::Slice const&)) table_cache.cc:112 (leveldb:x86_64+0x229cf9)
#6 leveldb::Version::Get(leveldb::ReadOptions const&, leveldb::LookupKey const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, leveldb::Version::GetStats*) version_set.cc:408 (leveldb:x86_64+0x27fbd6)
#7 leveldb::DBImpl::Get(leveldb::ReadOptions const&, leveldb::Slice const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*) db_impl.cc:1141 (leveldb:x86_64+0x8f922)
#8 firebase::firestore::local::LevelDbTransaction::Get(absl::string_view const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*) <null>:5344896 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x10109be79)
#9 +[FSTLevelDBMigrations schemaVersionWithTransaction:] <null>:5344896 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100cedd6a)
#10 +[FSTLevelDBMigrations runMigrationsWithTransaction:] <null>:5344896 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100cedf3e)
#11 -[FSTLevelDB start:] <null>:5344896 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100cbbf1e)
#12 -[FSTFirestoreClient initializeWithUser:usePersistence:] <null>:5344896 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100c5f2d3)
#13 __111-[FSTFirestoreClient initWithDatabaseInfo:usePersistence:credentialsProvider:userExecutor:workerDispatchQueue:]_block_invoke <null>:5344896 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100c5c87a)
#14 -[FSTDispatchQueue dispatchAsync:]::$_1::operator()() const <null>:5344896 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100bf6a7b)
#15 void std::__1::__invoke_void_return_wrapper<void>::__call<-[FSTDispatchQueue dispatchAsync:]::$_1&>(-[FSTDispatchQueue dispatchAsync:]::$_1&&&) <null>:5344896 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100bf69cc)
#16 std::__1::__function::__func<-[FSTDispatchQueue dispatchAsync:]::$_1, std::__1::allocator<-[FSTDispatchQueue dispatchAsync:]::$_1>, void ()>::operator()() <null>:5344896 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100bf5e6e)
#17 std::__1::function<void ()>::operator()() const <null>:5344896 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100be643b)
#18 firebase::firestore::util::AsyncQueue::ExecuteBlocking(std::__1::function<void ()> const&) <null>:5344896 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100a67d40)
#19 firebase::firestore::util::AsyncQueue::Wrap(std::__1::function<void ()> const&)::$_0::operator()() const <null>:5344896 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100a774ac)
#20 void std::__1::__invoke_void_return_wrapper<void>::__call<firebase::firestore::util::AsyncQueue::Wrap(std::__1::function<void ()> const&)::$_0&>(firebase::firestore::util::AsyncQueue::Wrap(std::__1::function<void ()> const&)::$_0&&&) <null>:5344896 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100a773cc)
#21 std::__1::__function::__func<firebase::firestore::util::AsyncQueue::Wrap(std::__1::function<void ()> const&)::$_0, std::__1::allocator<firebase::firestore::util::AsyncQueue::Wrap(std::__1::function<void ()> const&)::$_0>, void ()>::operator()() <null>:5344896 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100a7662e)
#22 std::__1::function<void ()>::operator()() const <null>:5344896 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100be643b)
#23 firebase::firestore::util::internal::DispatchAsync(NSObject<OS_dispatch_queue>*, std::__1::function<void ()>&&)::$_0::operator()(void*) const <null>:5344896 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100ac1d99)
#24 firebase::firestore::util::internal::DispatchAsync(NSObject<OS_dispatch_queue>*, std::__1::function<void ()>&&)::$_0::__invoke(void*) <null>:5344896 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100ac1cf8)
#25 __tsan::dispatch_callback_wrap(void*) <null>:5344896 (libclang_rt.tsan_iossim_dynamic.dylib:x86_64+0x62401)
#26 _dispatch_client_callout <null>:5344896 (libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x37eb)


Previous write of size 8 at 0x7b4c00051750 by thread T20 (mutexes: write M1134761197468718864):
#0 leveldb::port::AtomicPointer::Release_Store(void*) atomic_pointer.h:141 (leveldb:x86_64+0x57b76)
#1 leveldb::(anonymous namespace)::Limiter::SetAllowed(long) env_posix.cc:85 (leveldb:x86_64+0x158646)
#2 leveldb::(anonymous namespace)::Limiter::Acquire() env_posix.cc:63 (leveldb:x86_64+0x15c82e)
#3 leveldb::(anonymous namespace)::PosixEnv::NewRandomAccessFile(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, leveldb::RandomAccessFile**) env_posix.cc:354 (leveldb:x86_64+0x1461d6)
#4 leveldb::TableCache::FindTable(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, leveldb::Cache::Handle**) table_cache.cc:56 (leveldb:x86_64+0x228a50)
#5 leveldb::TableCache::NewIterator(leveldb::ReadOptions const&, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, leveldb::Table**) table_cache.cc:91 (leveldb:x86_64+0x229712)
#6 leveldb::VersionSet::MakeInputIterator(leveldb::Compaction*) version_set.cc:1274 (leveldb:x86_64+0x2b6b61)
#7 leveldb::DBImpl::DoCompactionWork(leveldb::DBImpl::CompactionState*) db_impl.cc:909 (leveldb:x86_64+0x7ffeb)
#8 leveldb::DBImpl::BackgroundCompaction() db_impl.cc:737 (leveldb:x86_64+0x7c79f)
#9 leveldb::DBImpl::BackgroundCall() db_impl.cc:675 (leveldb:x86_64+0x77f0a)
#10 leveldb::DBImpl::BGWork(void*) db_impl.cc:664 (leveldb:x86_64+0x77cf5)
#11 leveldb::(anonymous namespace)::PosixEnv::BGThread() env_posix.cc:648 (leveldb:x86_64+0x18885b)
#12 leveldb::(anonymous namespace)::PosixEnv::BGThreadWrapper(void*) env_posix.cc:555 (leveldb:x86_64+0x186995)


Location is heap block of size 416 at 0x7b4c00051600 allocated by thread     T10:
#0 operator new(unsigned long) <null>:5344912 (libclang_rt.tsan_iossim_dynamic.dylib:x86_64+0x67bd3)
#1 leveldb::InitDefaultEnv() env_posix.cc:678 (leveldb:x86_64+0x142aac)
#2 pthread_once <null>:5344912 (libclang_rt.tsan_iossim_dynamic.dylib:x86_64+0x28236)
#3 leveldb::Env::Default() env_posix.cc:691 (leveldb:x86_64+0x142a43)
#4 leveldb::Options::Options() options.cc:17 (leveldb:x86_64+0x1ea333)
#5 leveldb::Options::Options() options.cc:27 (leveldb:x86_64+0x1ea5a9)
#6 -[FSTLevelDB createDBWithDirectory:error:] <null>:5344912 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100cbcb5d)
#7 -[FSTLevelDB start:] <null>:5344912 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100cbb45d)
#8 -[FSTFirestoreClient initializeWithUser:usePersistence:] <null>:5344912 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100c5f2d3)
#9 __111-[FSTFirestoreClient initWithDatabaseInfo:usePersistence:credentialsProvider:userExecutor:workerDispatchQueue:]_block_invoke <null>:5344912 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100c5c87a)
#10 -[FSTDispatchQueue dispatchAsync:]::$_1::operator()() const <null>:5344912 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100bf6a7b)
#11 void std::__1::__invoke_void_return_wrapper<void>::__call<-[FSTDispatchQueue dispatchAsync:]::$_1&>(-[FSTDispatchQueue dispatchAsync:]::$_1&&&) <null>:5344912 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100bf69cc)
#12 std::__1::__function::__func<-[FSTDispatchQueue dispatchAsync:]::$_1, std::__1::allocator<-[FSTDispatchQueue dispatchAsync:]::$_1>, void ()>::operator()() <null>:5344912 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100bf5e6e)
#13 std::__1::function<void ()>::operator()() const <null>:5344912 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100be643b)
#14 firebase::firestore::util::AsyncQueue::ExecuteBlocking(std::__1::function<void ()> const&) <null>:5344912 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100a67d40)
#15 firebase::firestore::util::AsyncQueue::Wrap(std::__1::function<void ()> const&)::$_0::operator()() const <null>:5344912 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100a774ac)
#16 void std::__1::__invoke_void_return_wrapper<void>::__call<firebase::firestore::util::AsyncQueue::Wrap(std::__1::function<void ()> const&)::$_0&>(firebase::firestore::util::AsyncQueue::Wrap(std::__1::function<void ()> const&)::$_0&&&) <null>:5344912 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100a773cc)
#17 std::__1::__function::__func<firebase::firestore::util::AsyncQueue::Wrap(std::__1::function<void ()> const&)::$_0, std::__1::allocator<firebase::firestore::util::AsyncQueue::Wrap(std::__1::function<void ()> const&)::$_0>, void ()>::operator()() <null>:5344912 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100a7662e)
#18 std::__1::function<void ()>::operator()() const <null>:5344912 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100be643b)
#19 firebase::firestore::util::internal::DispatchAsync(NSObject<OS_dispatch_queue>*, std::__1::function<void ()>&&)::$_0::operator()(void*) const <null>:5344912 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100ac1d99)
#20 firebase::firestore::util::internal::DispatchAsync(NSObject<OS_dispatch_queue>*, std::__1::function<void ()>&&)::$_0::__invoke(void*) <null>:5344912 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100ac1cf8)
#21 __tsan::dispatch_callback_wrap(void*) <null>:5344912 (libclang_rt.tsan_iossim_dynamic.dylib:x86_64+0x62401)
#22 _dispatch_client_callout <null>:5344912 (libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x37eb)

Mutex M1134761197468718864 is already destroyed.

Thread T10 (tid=26697881, running) is a GCD worker thread

Thread T20 (tid=26701255, running) created by thread T10 at:
#0 pthread_create <null>:5344976 (libclang_rt.tsan_iossim_dynamic.dylib:x86_64+0x2678d)
#1 leveldb::(anonymous namespace)::PosixEnv::Schedule(void (*)(void*), void*) env_posix.cc:618 (leveldb:x86_64+0x153ef7)
#2 leveldb::DBImpl::MaybeScheduleCompaction() db_impl.cc:659 (leveldb:x86_64+0x779e9)
#3 leveldb::DB::Open(leveldb::Options const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, leveldb::DB**) db_impl.cc:1522 (leveldb:x86_64+0x9fdeb)
#4 -[FSTLevelDB createDBWithDirectory:error:] <null>:5344976 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100cbcfd3)
#5 -[FSTLevelDB start:] <null>:5344976 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100cbb45d)
#6 -[FSTFirestoreClient initializeWithUser:usePersistence:] <null>:5344976 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100c5f2d3)
#7 __111-[FSTFirestoreClient initWithDatabaseInfo:usePersistence:credentialsProvider:userExecutor:workerDispatchQueue:]_block_invoke <null>:5344976 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100c5c87a)
#8 -[FSTDispatchQueue dispatchAsync:]::$_1::operator()() const <null>:5344976 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100bf6a7b)
#9 void std::__1::__invoke_void_return_wrapper<void>::__call<-[FSTDispatchQueue dispatchAsync:]::$_1&>(-[FSTDispatchQueue dispatchAsync:]::$_1&&&) <null>:5344976 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100bf69cc)
#10 std::__1::__function::__func<-[FSTDispatchQueue dispatchAsync:]::$_1, std::__1::allocator<-[FSTDispatchQueue dispatchAsync:]::$_1>, void ()>::operator()() <null>:5344976 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100bf5e6e)
#11 std::__1::function<void ()>::operator()() const <null>:5344976 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100be643b)
#12 firebase::firestore::util::AsyncQueue::ExecuteBlocking(std::__1::function<void ()> const&) <null>:5344976 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100a67d40)
#13 firebase::firestore::util::AsyncQueue::Wrap(std::__1::function<void ()> const&)::$_0::operator()() const <null>:5344976 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100a774ac)
#14 void std::__1::__invoke_void_return_wrapper<void>::__call<firebase::firestore::util::AsyncQueue::Wrap(std::__1::function<void ()> const&)::$_0&>(firebase::firestore::util::AsyncQueue::Wrap(std::__1::function<void ()> const&)::$_0&&&) <null>:5344976 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100a773cc)
#15 std::__1::__function::__func<firebase::firestore::util::AsyncQueue::Wrap(std::__1::function<void ()> const&)::$_0, std::__1::allocator<firebase::firestore::util::AsyncQueue::Wrap(std::__1::function<void ()> const&)::$_0>, void ()>::operator()() <null>:5344976 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100a7662e)
#16 std::__1::function<void ()>::operator()() const <null>:5344976 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100be643b)
#17 firebase::firestore::util::internal::DispatchAsync(NSObject<OS_dispatch_queue>*, std::__1::function<void ()>&&)::$_0::operator()(void*) const <null>:5344976 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100ac1d99)
#18 firebase::firestore::util::internal::DispatchAsync(NSObject<OS_dispatch_queue>*, std::__1::function<void ()>&&)::$_0::__invoke(void*) <null>:5344976 (SampleApp:x86_64+0x100ac1cf8)
#19 __tsan::dispatch_callback_wrap(void*) <null>:5344976 (libclang_rt.tsan_iossim_dynamic.dylib:x86_64+0x62401)
#20 _dispatch_client_callout <null>:5344976 (libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x37eb)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race atomic_pointer.h:135 in leveldb::port::AtomicPointer::Acquire_Load() const
==================
```